# HTML readonly doesn't show in Chrome, but does in IE?

Tags: php, html, readonly

Using PHP I'm creating a table and one of the lines used is :

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='site[]' id='area$n' value='$area' size='20' readonly /></td>";
```

In IE this shows the row and the field is readonly, yet in Chrome the field isn't `readonly`

Looking at the source code in Chrome I can see readonly is there, yet if I inspect the element I only see:

```
<input type="text" name="site[]" id="area0" value="SouthEast" size="20">
```

I've tried setting `readonly='readonly'` but again it appears in the source code but not the element if I inspect it !

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

**UPDATE**
As a very quick test I've just created `tom.html` which only contains:

```
<table>     
    <td><input type='text' name='site[]' id='area0' value='SouthEast' size='20' readonly /></td>
</table>
```

There is no other code in that page and I get the same issue !

Comment: clear your cache

Comment: `ctrl+f5` clear browser cache

Comment: I've cleared my cache, hard reloaded the page and tried an incognito window with the same result. It looks like it should work but inspecting the element doesn't show `readonly` its very strange.

Comment: I should add if I change it to `disabled` then the field is disabled so it seems to be the readonly flag it doesn't like.

Comment: what version of chrome your are using ?

Comment: Version 62.0.3202.29 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: Found it.. I have a chrome extension that stops auto fill and it does it by marking any select or input as readonly.. it then sets readonly as false. Which causes my issue ! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using true.

```
<input type="text" name="site[]" id="area0" value="SouthEast" size="20" readonly='true'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, try readOnly, or [elementname].readOnly=true;

Answer (score -1):

You can try it with javascript:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
document.getElementById("myReadonlyInput").setAttribute("readonly", "true");

<!-- language: lang-js -->
document.getElementById('myReadonlyInput').setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
```